# Interpretation of two residual QQ plots from poisson regression

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, qq-plot

I have what I believe are an interesting QQ plot of the residuals of some sports data fitted using Poisson regression. My model is actually a live model to predict the number of remaining events in the game (basketball, soccer etc) from a set of explanatory variables. It looks also very much like the data is Poisson distributed, with equal mean and variance.

Residuals are as we know $r_i=Y_i-\mu_i$, where $Y_i$ are the observations, and $\mu_i$ the fitted mean of $Y_i$ ($Y_n$ may have different explanatory variables than, for example, $Y_{n-1}$).

Here is the first residual QQ plot of fitting my model to soccer match data (whole 90 minutes):
[image: Residual QQ plot number 1]

Interpreting QQ plots if I want to check for normality of some data is not too hard. It is easy to see that the residuals have too thick tails. But assuming the data is without a doubt Poisson distributed, something must therefore be wrong with $\mu_i$. Looking at the lower tail, I cannot reach any other conclusion than that the values of $\mu_i$ generally are too big - such that $r_i$ becomes too small. But also, looking at the upper tail, I cannot reach any other conclusion than that $\mu_i$ is too small - such that $r_i$ becomes too big. Is this a contradiction, or merely just a reflection that $\mu_i$ is not fitted good enough for extreme cases?

Comment: Note that the data are assumed to be *Poisson*, but the QQ plot is for normality. Beware of over-interpreting the appearance of the extreme tail.

Comment: Correct, but the residuals are normal, are they not?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: I would very much appreciate if you could elaborate. And, if they are not, what is the point of a residual QQ plot?

Comment: The individual y's are Poisson. $\hat y's$ are some complicated function of the set of $y$'s and the $x$s. The difference is not normal. The point of the residual plot is if the Poisson means aren't too small, the Poissons will be approximately normal. But the observations with small Poisson means won't be very well approximated by normals - and neither will the residuals. So you can't necessarily expect the QQ plot to match well everywhere, especially in the lower tail.

Comment: Scortchi has a nice illustration of @Glen_b's point about the residuals of GLMs in this post, [Checking residuals for normality in generalised linear models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92518/1036).

Comment: What I got from the indeed nice reply from @Scortchi, is that if I had a lot of observations for each explanatory variable I should expect to see normality in the residual QQ plot...

Comment: That whole discussion actually just made me more confused whether residuals should be normal or not.

Comment: Poisson regression explicitly assumes Poisson variation of the responses, so why would Normality even be a consideration? Why is it of any interest at all?

Comment: right now I just want to understand; to get a glimpse of the light of understanding you all are surrounded by. Therefore it is of interest

Comment: Eros, I think you misunderstood whuber's question. He wasn't asking "why are you interested in understanding this issue?", to paraphrase him, he was explaining that *the responses are assumed Poisson* so "why would it be important to check if residuals are normal?" -- because it's not clear why residuals from Poisson regression *would* necessarily look normal. Why is it of interest to check for normality of residuals? Why would that make sense as a thing to do?

Comment: Some other dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57044/what-is-the-expected-distribution-of-residuals-in-a-generalized-linear-model,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167404/glm-diagnostics-and-deviance-residual,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283674/where-are-the-residuals-in-a-glm,    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307221/why-residual-plots-are-used-for-diagnostic-of-glm