# Diagnostics and residual analysis for Poisson regression

Tags: panel-data, autocorrelation, poisson-regression, residuals

Recently, I was asked to check for serial correlation after doing a panel Poisson regression. I haven't seen such a test and in general, researchers (at least in the econom(etr)ics literature) don't report many diagnostics.

There is some discussion going on on this forum about the nature of residuals from a Poisson regression (see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92394/checking-residuals-for-normality-in-generalised-linear-models/92518#92518), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102960/interpretation-of-two-residual-qq-plots-from-poisson-regression?rq=1) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70558/diagnostic-plots-for-count-regression?rq=1)), specifically about the questions 1) whether residuals should normally distributed, and 2) if not, what their theoretical distribution is. My understanding so far is: 1) no, and 2) it's complicated.

Am I correct in thinking that the distribution of residuals for panel Poisson analysis is also complicated, probably more so than for cross-section; and that because of that, there simply are not as many formal diagnostic tests as for linear models?

(My immediate question is about serial correlation in panel Poisson models, but I would be interested in a more general discussion for Poisson models, non-linear models and other diagnostics than serial correlation)

Answer (score 2):

Since recently, you can use the [DHARMa R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html) to transform the residuals of any GL(M)M into a standardized space. Once this is done, you can visually assess / test residual problems such as deviations from the distribution, residual dependency on a predictor, heteroskedasticity or autocorrelation in the normal way. See the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) for worked-through examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, will have a look at the package.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you can order your residuals (typically in time or space), autocorrelation is just the correlation of the vector $[r_1, \ldots, r_{N-k}]$ with $[r_{1+k}, \ldots, r_{N}]$, for some lag, $k$.  Normality doesn't much matter for correlation (cf., [Pearson's or Spearman's correlation with non-normal data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3730/7290)).  It could matter for some tests of the significance of a correlation, but with autocorrelation you are typically more interested in the magnitude than its significance (by analogy, consider: [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/7290)).  If, for some reason you really wanted to *test* the correlation estimate, and didn't want to assume normality, you could bootstrap.